# Ductile metal makes sharper edge?

Tags: material-science, elements

I've read that, because it is so malleable, gold can be made into an extremely thin sheet, thinner than most other metals. Coming straight to the point, my question would be: While it would wear out practically instantly, would this allow gold to get a sharper edge than other metals, essentially becoming a super-single use scalpel? And how would it stack up against other super edges, like obsidian and diamond blades? Just curious.

Comment: Well, it would be ‘super sharp’ until any force were applied, at which point it would deform. So, not sharp in practice.

Comment: So, while sharp, it wouldn't be able to cut something or someone, as the simple act of trying to break their skin would already dull it without any effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ductility is not related to the property of accept a sharp edge. As you said, it can be done also with brittle materials like obsidian or diamond.

Really it is more difficult to sharpen a gold sword than a quenched and tempered steel one. Fragments of material goes along with the cutting tool, instead of falling down as small chips. Sharpen is more a cutting process than a plastic deformation one.

But a gold sword with a sharp edge can hurt a lot anyway

Comment: About resharpening: scythes in partcular are also sharpened using hammering. This way of sharpening is called 'peening a scythe'. Resharpening by peening uses ductility of the material of course. I don't know how many cycles of resharpening by peening is possible. Presumably the steel will work harden.